# Dont allow timeout on a page, though it is in an application that has a timeout

Tags: timeout

I am working on a .jsp page that is in an application that has a timeout for any page in that application.  Is there any way around this, or would it have to be created in a separate application.  I know this is usually done in the xml file, but was curious if there was any other option?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to poll back to the server and hit a page that would re-set the timeout timer. This could be done with some fairly simple javascript, and jQuery makes it even simpler.